# Does a von Neumann algebra correspond to a quantum system?

Tags: hilbert-space, operators, quantum-information, mathematical-physics, mathematics

We usually associate a quantum system with a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and consider the set of bounded operators on $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$. Especially the set of unit-trace and positive (semi-definite) operators, $S(\mathcal{H})$, is identified with the set of quantum states of the given quantum system.

Can we say the same with a von Neumann algbera $V$? In particular, can we say that von Neumann algebras with the faithful trace (Type $I_{\text{fin}}$ and Type $II_1$) correspond to a quantum system? Can we pick up unit trace positive elements of $V$ and identify them with quantum states?

If so, what are the examples of quanutum systems that *must* be described with a von Neumann algebra, not with $\mathcal{B(H)}$ with some Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$?

Comment: Have you read this? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363002/

Answer (score 2):

In the axiomatic algebraic formalism, say of the Ostwalder-Schrader axioms of nets of local algebras, it turns that the local algebra must all be isomorphic to the unique hyperfinite factor of type $III_1$. Hence specific theories depend upon how these algebras embed within  each other.

For more details, see the paper *The Role of Type III Facyors in QFT* by Yngvason on the Arxiv and which was presented at the von Neumann centennial conference at Budapest in 2003.